# Problem with sending MMS with png image using Twilio

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-api

We are having an issue with sending MMS with PNG images. We previously use that and all works well now it failed.

The code example is here:

```
 $client = new Client(env('TWILIO_SID'), env('TWILIO_TOKEN'));
$message = $client->messages->create(
            $number,
            [
                'from' => env('TWILIO_FROM'),
                'body' => $content,
                "statusCallback" => "https://OUR_URL.com/api/twilio_web_hooks",
                "mediaUrl" => $image_url,
            ]
        );
```

We get this error:

> 12300 Twilio is unable to process the Content-Type of the provided URL. Please see Twilio's  [documentation on accepted content types](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types)  for more information on valid Content-Types.

[image]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: you can take a look on update

Comment: I can see 3 possible issues: 1st is make sure the $image_url is a publicly available url, 2nd is envelop your $image_url into an array like this: `"mediaUrl": [$image_url]` and 3rd is make sure your $image_url has an extension

Comment: All three are OK :( take a look added image from Twilio logs.

Comment: It is not really about whether the image URL has any specific "extension", but what `Content-Type` header the response contains. (_Usually_ web servers determine the mime type based on the extension, at least when serving static files directly. But we have no information whatsoever here, what this image URL actually is, where it comes from, how it gets served, so no way to tell for sure right now.)

Comment: Change the extension to what the file type actually is. I took a .jpg and changed it to .png and got the same error you have. Are you sure this is a .png file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a HEX editor and see if you see PNG towards the top.

PNG files start with 'PNG', . jpg files should have 'exif'or 'JFIF' somewhere in the beginning.

[image]